# Angular NgRx Unit Test Failing

Tags: html, angular, typescript, unit-testing, ngrx

I don't understand why my unit tests fail.
How do I check that my asynchronous condition has been fulfilled after store dispatch ?
I want to check 3 things:
1/ My component is truthy afer dispatch (after condition is set to true)
2/ The inner text is correct when the mode is AddMode ('La note a été ajoutée)
3/ The inner text is correct when the mode is not AddMode ('la note a été modifiée')

I am using 'fakeAsync' to test asynchronous behavior but it doesn't works as expected.

What am I missing ?

Thank you all.

HTML code:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(isToastVisible$ | async)">
  <div *ngIf="(isAddMode| async)"
    class="position-fixed bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x p-3 border border-success bg-success text-white"
    style="z-index: 11">La note a été ajoutée !</div>

  <div *ngIf="!(isAddMode | async)"
    class="position-fixed bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x p-3 border border-success bg-success text-white"
    style="z-index: 11">La note a été modifiée !</div>
</ng-container>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { showAddEditNoteToast, AddEditNoteModalMode } from 'src/app/reducers/selectors/selectors';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toast',
  templateUrl: './toast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toast.component.scss']
})
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {

  public isToastVisible$: Observable<boolean>;
  public isAddMode$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isToastVisible$ = this.store.pipe(select(showAddEditNoteToast));
    this.isAddMode$ = this.store.pipe(select(AddEditNoteModalMode));
  }
}
```

SPEC.TS:

```
import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ToastComponent } from './toast.component';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { Initialstate } from '../../app/reducers/index';
import { setFormMode, showAddEditNoteModal } from 'src/app/reducers/actions/actions';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('ToastComponent', () => {
  let component: ToastComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ToastComponent>;
  let store: MockStore;
  const initialState = Initialstate;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ToastComponent],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState })
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore)
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ToastComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create Toast component ', fakeAsync(() => {
    store.dispatch(showAddEditNoteModal({ showAddEditNoteModal: true }));
    tick();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should render text - La note a été ajoutée !', fakeAsync(() => {
    store.dispatch(setFormMode({ isAddMode: true }));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    const text = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(text).toEqual('La note a été ajoutée !')
  }))
});
```

Comment: What do the existing tests fail with?

Comment: It block #2 error: Expected <div id="root2" _nghost-a-c52 ng-version="12.0.5"> to equal 'La note a été ajoutée !'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first test should pass even without the action dispatch or `tick`, as it's just checking the component instance was created rather than anything specific that the action does.

In the second one, you need to check against the text content of the `div` element:

`const text = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div')).nativeElement.innerText;`

You also might need to use `trim()` on `text`.

Comment: The first test works indeed without async.

Comment: The second test throws an error:
Error: Expected '' to equal 'La note a été ajoutée !'.
I believe the constant test returns empty....

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I remove the dispatch function and set the variables directly: 
 component.isToastVisible$ = of(true);        
 component.isAddMode$ = of(false);
 tick();
 fixture.detectChanges();

Comment: That's fine as the test is more isolated, but you might not need the`tick` or `fakeAsync` anymore

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can remove `tick` and `fakesync`.